# Writing a tokenizer for an english text in python with nltk and regex

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I want to write a tokenizer for an English text and I'm working with the RegExp tokenizer from the `nltk` module in python.

This is the expression right now I use to split the words:

```
[\w\.]+
```

(the "." so something like `u.s.a` doesn't get butchered.)

Problem: At the same time i want to remove the punctuation from the word: `usa`.

Of course I can do it in separate steps but I thought there has to be a smoother way than iterating over the whole text again just to remove punctuation.
Since it needs to be scalable I want to optimize the runtime as best as I can.
I'm pretty new to Regular Expressions and have a really hard time, so I'm really happy for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

The module uses more then regular expressions alone (specifically trained sets) and does a pretty good job on its own with abbreviations, really:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

text = """
    In recent times, the U.S. has had to endure difficult 
    political times and many trials and tribulations. 
    Maybe things will get better soon - but only with the 
    right punctuation marks. Am I right, Dr.?"""

words = []
for nr, sent in enumerate(sent_tokenize(text, 1)):
    print("{}. {}".format(nr, sent))
    for word in word_tokenize(sent):
        words.append(word)

print(words)
```

Don't reinvent the wheel here with own regular expressions.